# Sklearn multiclass classification class order

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have three classes [-1,0,1] and I am running multi class logistic regression on them. When I run logreg.predict_proba(x) it returns a an array [.25, .5, .25] does this mean that position 0 is class -1, position 1 is class 0, and position 2 is class 1? In other words, how does the logistic regression map the classes to the output columns? Does it do it by numerical order? Or based on the first class it sees?

Answer (score 5):

You can verify the order of the classes using the classes attribute of your logistic regression classifier. For example, if the classifier is named logreg then

```
logreg.classes_
```

will reveal the order of the classes.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba .

Comment: Thanks solved my issue. But there is a typo. Correct is `whatevermodel.classes_`

Comment: My answer clearly states: "For example, if the classifier is named logreg then logreg.classess_".

Comment: yeah you are right :)  but you've made a typo it's classes_, not classess_

Comment: Well spotted, thank you.